# Modeling a relationship that relies on two nodes

Tags: neo4j

I'm modeling legal cases with **Attorneys**, **Firms**, **Judges**, **Cases** and **Parties** and I'm trying to model the relationship between an **Attorney** and a **Party** on a **Case**. The trouble is that my current model doesn't scope the relationship to a *particular case*, that is, once an **Attorney** has a **REPRESENTS** relationship to a **Party**, then she is *always* associated with that **Party**, even on unrelated **Cases**. I know that relationships can only have two nodes on them, so how do I model this without creating a SQL-like join table? That is, I want this (even though I can't have it):

```
(Attorney)-[REPRESENTS]->(Party+Case)
```

Here's a simplified sketch of my models:

```
(Attorney {email:, ...})
  -[REPRESENTS]->(Party)
  -[MEMBER_OF]->(Firm)

(Party {name:, ...})
  -[PARTY_IN {role: <plaintiff, defenadant, ...>}]->(Case)

(Firm {email_domain:, ...})

(Case {title:, case_number:, court_house:, ...)

(Judge {name:,...})
  -[PRESIDING_OVER]->(Case)
```

Answer (score 0):

Look into the use of intermediate nodes.  Not a perfect example, but this might help you think through the data model.

http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2013/10/22/neo4j-modelling-hyper-edges-in-a-property-graph/

The idea is that you might want to create a relationship node that connects the `Case`, `Party`, and `Attorney`

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may want to break out your PARTY_IN roles as their own nodes.

So you might have something like this:

```
(:Party)-[:PARTY_AS]->(:Defendant)-[:IN]->(:Case)
(:Attorney)-[:REPRESENTS]->(:Defendant)-[:IN]->(:Case)
```

You can either use separate labels for :Defendant, :Plaintiff, etc (recommended), or have a more generalized (:Role) with a type field.

If you wanted a query to give you the parties and attorneys for a case, you might use something like:

```
MATCH (case:Case)
WHERE case.id = 123
WITH case
MATCH (party:Party)-[:PARTY_AS]->(role)-[:IN]->(case)
WITH party, role
MATCH (attorney:Attorney)-[:REPRESENTS]->(role)
RETURN LABELS(role) AS role, COLLECT(attorney) AS attorneys, party
```

(using collect here as multiple attorneys may represent a party in a case)